# Display the student details who borrowed books of more than one Author

Tags: sql

Borrow table with

```
studentnumber, bookid,
```

Book table

```
bookid, authorid
```

Student table

```
stdentnumber studentname, branchid
```

Branch table

```
branchid , branchname
```

I am using oracle 11g. Display the student details who borrowed books of more than one Author

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're no free do-my-homework-service. What have you done so far and what is not working?

Comment: At least show some work done by yourself instead of asking us to write for you.

Comment: here is a hint `select studentnumber from borrow_table group by studentnumber having count(*) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a count distinct call to count the number of authors each student checked out and use the `exists` operator to correlate it with the students table:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM   students s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT   br.studentnumber
              FROM     borrow br
              JOIN     book b ON br.bookid = b.bookid
              WHERE    br.studentnumber = s.studentnumber
              GROUP BY studentnumber
              HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT authorid) > 1)
```